# There is an issue with the time in my macbook air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My laptop displays the time correctly in the menu bar, but when it records an activity, like the creation of a file, a sent message in iMessage, a reminder, it always shows the time as 7pm with whatever minutes are accurate. So if I send an iMessage at 3:22pm it would appear as sent at 7:22pm. And if I make a folder at 10:00am it appears as created at 7:00pm.This is driving me crazy. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the PRAM?

> Shut down your Mac. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command
>   (⌘), Option, P, and R. You will need to hold these keys down
>   simultaneously in step 4. Turn on the computer. Press and hold the
>   Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears. Hold the keys
>   down until the computer restarts and you hear the startup sound for
>   the second time. Release the keys.

If this doesn't help, your PRAM battery may need to be replaced. Not a huge deal.